# Is it possible to specialize an object to a subclass on the fly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pydantic

I am currently in a situation where I have a class (Item) and a subclass (ScoredItem) and a function which makes an Item to a ScoredItem. The code works fine, but it requires me to re-create an existing object. It could happen that the `Item` gets another attribute with a default value which would break the code. For example, if `Item` got an attribute `total_interactions : int = 0`, then the item list inserted into `score_items` would likely not have `total_interactions=0`. But if `score_items`is not adjusted, then it silently fails. Is there a way to prevent this? Something like `scored_item = ScoredItem(score=0.123, **item)`? Or `item.score = 0.123; scored_item = ScoredItem(item)`?

I thought about [composition vs. inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53354/562769), but there are good indicators it should be inheritance.

### MVCE

```
import random
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Item(BaseModel):
    item_id: str
    title: str


class ScoredItem(Item):
    score: float


def get_items() -> List[Item]:
    # generate n random items
    n = 10
    return [Item(item_id=str(i), title="foobar") for i in range(n)]


def score_items(items: List[Item]) -> List[ScoredItem]:
    scored_items = []
    for item in items:
        scored_item = ScoredItem(
            # Everything an Item has
            item_id=item.item_id, title=item.title,
            # Plus the score
            score=random.random()
        )
    return scored_items


items = get_items()
scored_items = score_items(items)
```

Comment: Why not using `scored_item = ScoredItem(score=0.123, **item.dict())` ?

Comment: This might work :-) - is pydantics `.dict()` guaranteed to have only things that are in the constructor / have every attribute?

Comment: I think every attribute, learned about pydantic only an hour ago from this post :)

Comment: It's takes arguments to change what is returned, see the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something you just need `ScoredItem(score=0.123, **dict(item))`.

Or you can use `item.dict()`, see [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/) for details on the differences.